# jquery: $.data() returns boolean instead of string

Tags: jquery, html

I have got the following html element:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="sortArrow down active" data-order_asc="false">
      <img src="/static/web/img/down-active.gif">
</a>
```

The problem is that

```
$('a.sortArrow.down.inactive').data('order_asc')
```

returns **boolean false instead of string "false"**. There seems to be some kind of conversion that I don't really ask for. I would like string "false" to return.

Comment: `$('a.sortArrow.down.inactive').data('order_asc').toString();` use this to convert it to string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented here - http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5.

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null).

If you want the attribute string value, use `attr()`, eg

```
$('a.sortArrow.down.inactive').attr('data-order_asc')
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way: further reading :  [Attributes](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/attributes/)

```
$('a.sortArrow.down.inactive').attr('data-order_asc');
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the jQuery API "Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null)."

To retrieve the value's attribute as a string without any attempt to convert it, use the attr() method.